# how to change form action using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Im trying to change the form action based from two ahref tags, one is button and other one is text. when it clicks the button, the action of form should be /profile.php?id= and if text was clicked the action should be /profile.php?uid= im stuck at this problem. here is my code in html:

```
 <a href = "profile.php?/edit/employment-information/" id="edit"><input type="button" name="editemp" id="edit" value="Edit">
 <a href="profile.php?/add/employment-information/" id="add">Add Information</a>
 <form name="empform" method="post" action="profile.php" autofocus id="form">
<input name="employ" type="text" id="employ" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{3,20}" placeholder="Who is your employer?">
<input name="position" type="text" id="position" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{3,20}" placeholder="What is your job description?">
<input name="empadd" type="text" id="empadd" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9@#$% ,]{5,30}" placeholder="Where is your work address?">
<input name="empcont" type="text" id="empcont" pattern="[0-9]{11}" title="11-digit number" placeholder="Contact number">
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself, do you have any jQuery code to make this work?

Comment: i have no idea. i just deleted the code and formulating new one

Comment: Also, kinda weird to wrap an anchor around an input, this is very confusing as to what it is supposed to do

Comment: im sorry about it. i removed the ahref tag on button. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple add an eventlistner to both anchors, each anchor gets its own code to change form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#edit').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Dont actually go to the location of the anchor
         $('#form').attr('action', 'URL_IF_EDIT_IS_CLICKED'); // change it to this url
    });

    $('#add').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Dont actually go to the location of the anchor
        $('#form').attr('action', 'URL_IF_ADD_IS_CLICKED'); // change it to this url
    });
});
```

---

If you have more anchors, the following method might be easier:
First add a class to the anchors (lets say 'formActionChanger'), then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // eventlistener on the anchors:
    $('.formActionChanger').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Dont actually go to the location of the anchor
        var newAction;
        // start a switch to decide which new action is going to be used
        switch(this.id){
            case 'edit': newAction = 'URL_IF_EDIT_IS_CLICKED'; break;
            case 'add':  newAction = 'URL_IF_ADD_IS_CLICKED';  break;
            default:     newAction = 'DEFAULT_URL';            break;
        }
        $('#form').attr('action', newAction); // change it to this url
    });
});
```

Comment: i have one more question, why it does not display in my address bar the url of a button or the text?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the form action with

```
$("#form").attr("action", "your new action here");
```

All you do is stick this inside a `click` handler:

```
$("#elementID").click(function() {
    //change form here
});
```

Not really sure which buttons on your code should change this, so I made it pretty generic for you to modify.